# How to correctly set the initial route for nested tabs using Expo Router in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, expo-router

I'm building a React Native application using Expo with Expo Router for navigation and I'm encountering an issue with setting the initial tab when the app starts. Despite configuring the initial route name in my tabs configuration, the app defaults to loading the `index.tsx` file. I'm looking to have the 'watch' tab as the initial view.

The project is structured as follows, with a specific focus on the app and (tabs) directories where my `_layout.tsx` files reside:

```
src/
├── app/
│   ├── (screens)/
│   │   ├── _layout.tsx        # Root layout for screens
│   │   └── ...                # Other screens
│   ├── (tabs)/
│   │   ├── _layout.tsx        # Layout for tabs
│   │   ├── account.tsx        # Account tab screen
│   │   └── watch.tsx          # Watch tab screen
│   ├── _layout.tsx            # Main layout file
│   └── index.tsx              # Entry point
├── common/
├── components/
├── config/
└── constants/
```

In the `app/_layout.tsx`, I've specified `(tabs)` in `RootLayoutNav` as the route to be loaded. The `_layout.tsx` inside the `(tabs)` directory then sets 'watch' as the initial route. Here's the relevant part of the `app/_layout.tsx` file:

```
function RootLayoutNav() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }}  />
    </Stack>
  );
}
```

And here is my configuration in `app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx` file:

```
return (
        <Tabs screenOptions={{
            initialRouteName: 'watch',
            tabBarActiveTintColor: Colors.primary,
            tabBarLabelStyle: {
                fontFamily: 'mon-sb',
            },
        }}>
            <Tabs.Screen name="watch" options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Watch',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Ionicons name="play-circle-outline" size={size} color={color} />
            }} />

            <Tabs.Screen name="account" options={{
                tabBarLabel: 'Account',
                tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => <Ionicons name="person-circle-outline" size={size} color={color} />
            }} />
        </Tabs>
    )
```

Any help or insight into why this is happening and how to resolve it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got something on expo github repositiory:

*`initialRouteName` came from React Navigation, we'll probably rename it. `initialRouteName` renders the default screen for a navigator, this is useful for modals where you always want a screen under the modal. We don't have a dedicated static redirect-config API, I recommend creating an index route and redirecting to the desired screen inside. Preferably you'd just have an index route.*

https://github.com/expo/router/issues/763#issuecomment-1635316964

**Solution:**

inside `index.tsx` file I write this

```
return <Redirect href="(tabs)/watch" />;
```

Answer (score 0):

[initialRouteName](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/bottom-tab-navigator/#initialroutename) is not part of `screenOptions`. It should be on the same level, something like this:

```js
<Tabs
  initialRouteName="watch"
  screenOptions={{
    ...
  }}
>
...
</Tabs>
```